# Why did Sonya ask to see Cole's Dragon marking, if she already knew he was one of Earth's champions?

Tags: mortal-kombat

When Sonya first meets Cole in *Mortal Kombat* (2021), she points her torch at him and asks to see his Dragon marking:

[image]

Sonya had photos of Cole in her gallery:

[image]

That means she already knew he was one of Earth's champions, so why did she still ask to see his marking?

Comment: Having a good publicist doesn’t translate into being reality. It’s one thing to win a few matches with commentating by Joe Rogan; it’s quite another to compete for the earth realm against magic outworlders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dragon marking isn't necessarily about the target's combat skill in public competitions, but rather that they have been mystically chosen and marked as Earth's champion. At that, as occasionally happens in works with mystical tattoos, people may find ways to fake them that would not be evident in lower fidelity reproductions such as photographs.